# usage of setTimeout function in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I.m currently following a tutorial about how to load content from a MYSQL db without reloading the page.

I just want to understand the use of `setTimeout` in this code. What's it for? I tried removing that part and ajax still works. Why would you need to delay a task, isn't ajax meant to be realtime update?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    done(); 
});

function done() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        updates();
        done();
    }, 200);
}

function updates() {
    $.getJSON("update.php", function (data) {
        $("ul").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            $("ul").append("<li>ID: " + this['msg_id'] + "</li><br /><li>ID: " + this['msg'] + "</li><br />");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: setTimeout reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Comment: @JanDvorak delete that :)

Comment: @TusharGupta reworded to not refer to your comment ;-)

Comment: It's a recursive function that gets executed about five times every second. Without the timeout, it would be executed a million times every second and the browser would crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that code, the `setTimeout` is being used to get updates from the server 5 times a second (which is probably too frequently). Without it, it only get the updates once (if `updates()` is ever called).

Answer (score 0):

The setTimeout appears in the done() function, and when the setTimeout executes (after 200ms) it calls itself recursively. Thus the updates() function will be called every 200ms for the life of the page.

If update.php is some kind of message stream, then this code requires the setTimeout to continuously poll for new messages and append them to a list.

Answer (score 0):

[settimeout](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-use-jquery-settimeout-function.html) and [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

In your code `setTimeout` calls `done` function and `updates()` function after every `200 millisecond`

```
function done() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        updates();
        done();
    }, 200);
}
```

like you if you remove `setTimeout` it still works

```
  function done() {
            updates();
            done();
    }
```

as it creates infinite loop of `done` function

but no delay which was caused by `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

The function `setTimeout` takes a function and a number as parameter, it executes the function after the given number of milliseconds.

In your code it means: the function `updates()` is called every 200 milliseconds - 5 times a second.

Read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

It's being used to delay recursion by 200 ms. If you remove the timeout, the loop will work just the same, but you'll probably run out of memory before too long.

A more interesting/instructive take on this example would be to pass done to updates as a callback and call it on success.

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) to poll regardless of the resource returning a result.

This version will only re-execute in case of success.

Of course if you want your code to poll always, regardless so it can recover from an error at the server, you should not change. But 200 MS is in any case far too often

```
$(function () {
  updates(); 
});


function updates() {
    $.getJSON("update.php", function (data) {
        $("ul").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            $("ul").append("<li>ID: " + this['msg_id'] + "</li>"+
                           "<li> " + this['msg'] + "</li>");
        });
        setTimeout(updates, 10000); // do it again in 10 seconds
    });
}
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this and left no comment is more than unhelpful.